# Using trigger in one table and updating another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updateTrigger
   ON  dbo.Education 
   AFTER UPDATE
   AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT (UPDATE( HighestDegreeDoc) OR UPDATE (GPA) OR UPDATE (CreditHours))
    RETURN
UPDATE dbo.School
set Uploaded =1
from dbo.School
JOIN inerted i ON i.Uploaded = School.Uploaded
END
GO
```

What is Wrong with this code. i am trying to update field in School table , field uploaded when (HighestDegreeDoc , GPA, CrediHours) update in Education Table. NOTE Education Table has more than 15 field,  (Uploaded Field in School table update only when these 3 field change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess....

JOIN inerted i ON i.Uploaded = School.Uploaded

Should be...

```
JOIN inserted i ON i.SchoolId = School.SchoolId
```

Looks like Updated is some sort of flag that you are setting.  You probably want to join on an ID column instead.

Comment: yes this is right , i am trying to put flag. ok , i will try ID

Answer (score 0):

It's only a typo error : it's `join inserted` ;)

And I don't think your join condition is good.

Can you give us the ddl ?